# PHP in cron is logging all output to mail, but I want to only log when there is an error only

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I have a PHP script that runs every 2 minutes via cron. Since this php file has an output, but not an error. It keeps logging the output and sending a message to the user's inbox on the system. This is just an internal locally hosted ubuntu system. I find the inbox notifications useful as it can give me a sense when something is wrong. I can easily make the cron php files silent by appending > /dev/null 1>&2 -- But this will also silence the php errors when it arises. How can I still keep cron sending me the inbox message ONLY if there is a PHP error?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `>/dev/null`, leave out `2>&1` (I assume `1>&2` in the question was a typo for this). Then standard output will be discarded, but standard error will still be sent as mail.